# Array concat returns empty array

Tags: javascript

I'm adding several items to an array using `concat` in an event-handler as follows:

```
var selectedValues = [];
$.each($('#selected-levels').data("kendoListBox").dataSource.data(), function(i, item) {
    selectedValues.concat([ item.id ])
});

return {
    "selected" : selectedValues
};
```

this always returns `{level-selected: Array(0)}`
even though I have checked that there are some `item`s in the `dataSource` (by stepping through with debugger)

why don't the items appear in the array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**`concat` doesn't mutate the array**, you need to set the value back to `selectedValues`

```
selectedValues = selectedValues.concat([ item.id ])
```

Or use `push`

```
selectedValues.push( item.id )
```

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, the answer was already hidden in your question, in your question title more exactly.

Actually concat **returns** the correct new array you want... you just never used the return value !

You have to be aware that the array is not modified *in place*, but a fresh copy is returned.

So `selectedValues.concat([ item.id ])` should be replaced by `selectedValues = selectedValues.concat([ item.id ])` if you want to do anything.